# Integral of $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(a \cdot \ln(x))\sin (b \cdot \ln(x))}{\ln(x)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to calculate the integral $$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin\Big(a \cdot \ln(x)\Big)\cdot \sin \Big(b \cdot \ln(x)\Big)}{\ln(x)} dx, $$
but am stuck. I tried using Simpsons' rules and got here:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\cos\Big((a+b) \cdot \ln(x)\Big) - \cos \Big((a-b) \cdot \ln(x)\Big)}{2\ln(x)} dx, $$
but alas, that also got me nowhere. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: when you meet $\int{\frac{e^{-x}\cos tx}{x}dx}$ type. let it be I(t) and take derivative of $t$, then you do integrate with $\int{e^{-x}\sin tx\,dx}$ type for $I'(t)$, then anti-derivative $I'(t)$ will lead to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

For $c \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{align}
\int \limits_0^\infty \frac{1 - \cos(c t)}{t} \, \mathrm{e}^{-t} \, \mathrm{d} t  &= \int \limits_0^\infty \int \limits_0^c \sin(u t) \, \mathrm{d} u \, \mathrm{e}^{-t} \, \mathrm{d} t = \int \limits_0^c \int \limits_0^\infty \sin(u t) \mathrm{e}^{-t} \, \mathrm{d} t \, \mathrm{d} u = \int \limits_0^c \frac{u}{1+u^2} \, \mathrm{d} u \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \ln(1 + c^2) \, ,
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
\int \limits_0^1 \frac{\sin[a \ln(x)] \sin[b \ln(x)]}{\ln(x)} \, \mathrm{d} x &= \int \limits_0^1 \frac{\cos[(a+b)\ln(x)] - \cos[(a-b) \ln(x)]}{- 2 \ln(x)} \, \mathrm{d} x \\
&\!\!\!\stackrel{x = \mathrm{e}^{-t}}{=} \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{\left(1 - \cos[(a - b) t]\right) - \left(1 - \cos[(a+b) t]\right)}{2t} \, \mathrm{e}^{-t} \, \mathrm{d} t \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left(\ln[1 + (a-b)^2] - \ln[1 + (a+b)^2]\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \ln \left(\frac{1+(a-b)^2}{1+(a+b)^2}\right) \, .
\end{align}

Comment: Why the $\frac{1}{-2\ln(x)}$?

Comment: @Riley Since $\sin(\alpha) \sin(\beta) = \frac{1}{2}[\cos(\alpha - \beta) - \cos(\alpha + \beta)] = \frac{1}{-2}[\cos(\alpha + \beta) - \cos(\alpha - \beta)]. $ The minus sign is missing in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that it would be very pleasant.

After your simplification, you face two integrals looking like
$$I=\int \frac {\cos(k \log(x))} {\log(x)} \,dx$$ First, let $x=e^t$ to make
$$I=\int \frac{e^t \cos (k t)}{t}\,dt$$ and consider that you need the real part of
$$I=\int \frac{e^t\,e^{ikt}}t\,dt=\int \frac{e^{(1+ik)t}}t\,dt$$ Now, let $(1+ik)t=u$ to make
$$I=\int \frac {e^u} u \,du=\text{Ei}(u)$$ where appears the exponential integral function.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the integral by substituting $\ ln(x) = t$ and putting the appropriate limits, we get:

$$\ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{2t}\cdot[\cos(a+b)t-\cos(a-b)t]dt$$

We can now rewrite this as:

$$\ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{2}\cdot[\frac{1-\cos(a-b)t}{t} - \frac{1-\cos(a+b)t}{t}]dt$$

Now, notice we only need to evaluate the integral

$$\ I_1(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t}\cdot\frac{1-\cos(at)}{t}dt$$

Taking the derivate  on both sides, we get:

$$ \ I'_1(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \ e^{-t}\cdot \sin(at)dt$$

Integrating by parts, we obtain:

$$ \ I'_1(a) = \frac{e^{-t}}{1+a^2} \cdot [-\sin(at)-a\cos(at)] \rvert_0^{\infty} $$

$$ \ I'_1(a) = \frac{a}{1+a^2} $$

Integrating with respect to $\ a$, we get:

$$\ I_1(a) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \ln(1+a^2) + C $$

Note that at $\ a = 0$, $\ I_1(0) = 0$. Thus, $\ C = 0$.

Using the above expression, we can easily compute the value of the given integral:

$$ \ I = \frac{1}{2} \cdot [ \ I_1(a-b) - \ I_1(a+b) ] $$

Plugging in the values of the expressions, we finally obtain:

$$ \ I = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \ln\frac{1+(a-b)^2}{1+(a+b)^2}  $$